# Configure generating path with Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

If there are files called `members/alice.md` and `members/bob.md`, the Jekyll generated position will be `members/alice.html` and `members/bob.html`. How can I set them to be `members/alice/index.html` and `members/bob/index.html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [Permalinks](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/).

Here are 2 approaches that may suit you:

**1. Per-page YAML frontmatter**

If you just want specific pages to have that behavior, just add a `permalink:` option in your YAML frontmatter for your Markdown post.

For example: In `members/alice.md`'s YAML frontmatter add:

```
---
permalink: members/alice/
---
```

**2. Edit the `_config.yml` file**

As per the documentation I've linked above, the simplest way (which I recommend) way to achieve this is with Jekyll's built-in `pretty` option.

Add this in your `_config.yml`:

`permalink: pretty`

This removes the .html from the static output by making all posts have their own folder and named as index.html.

Your browser would then display this as `yoursite.com/members/alice/`, note that the `index.html` is hidden, a behavior on most browsers. If you head on over to peek at the output `_site` folder, you'll see a folder in `members` named `alice`, and a file `index.html` inside.

**Also note that:**

You need to restart the Jekyll server every time you make a change in `_config.yml`, unlike other files that the Jekyll server will detect changes and regenerate, this configuration file will not and the WEBrick server must be restarted for changes to take effect. :)

You could also refer to the documentation on other more customizable options as well. [Here's also a tutorial for reference too.](http://www.davehulihan.com/2012/08/17/jekyll-pages-with-pretty-urls.html)

Comment: Tutorial reference link in your answer no longer works :(.